# Controlling read/writes to memory mapped files (windows)

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-mapped-files

Are you meant to protect against simultanously reads/writes to file mapped memory that is open by multiple processes?

For example if a string in the memory is "hello" and one process writes "hi..." over it, am I correct to say that another process that reads at the same time may get an intermittant value like "hi.lo"?

Basically what I am asking is how do people protect again these sorts of things. Are you meant to use semaphores? Do these work across processes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you need to protect against multiple writers or avoid reading partial updates then a shared Mutex / Semaphore used by each process would work to control access to the shared data.

There is some sample code which does this at the bottom of this MSDN article: [Memory-Mapped Files in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)